# Conditional Static Time Entry in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I need to insert a STATIC time into excel based on a condition in a cell.  i.e. Cell A1 = "A" then insert the static time.  Any ideas?

Comment: That can be resolved by using VBA. See link: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/828068-automatic-static-date.html  
I don't think there's another way to it.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+: will insert the current time (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-shortcut-and-function-keys-HP010073848.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(A1="A","10:43:00","")
```

Comment: That will only work if the time you want to appear is always 10:43. I think the OP is looking for a way to dynamically insert the current time at the moment the cell contents becomes "A" in the case of cell A1.

Comment: do you mean    =IF(A1="A",NOW(),"")  ?

Comment: Sadly NOW() refreshes every time the worksheet recalculates, so assuming the OP wanted to record the time of change for multiple rows or once but then continue to use the workbook, NOW() wouldn't quite do the job, VBA is needed.